# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, xslt

I am working on an XSLT that uses a C# script.

I have a function DateParse that is supposed to take a string which is a date stored as "yyyy-MM-dd". I want it to return the string as a date stored as "yyyyMMdd"

I tried the following (among other things):

```
public DateTime DateParse(string dateString)
{
     string result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd",
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     return result;
     }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
```

Anyone have any ideas? I am lost and have tried so much.

Kind regards

Edit:

As requested, I am sharing the xslt code that executes the C# function here.

```
<xsl:variable name="ExtractDate" select="ms:DateParse(/Extraction/Row[1]/AsOfDate)" />
```

`AsOfDate` is a column in a xlsx file that contains values `2021-09-10`, or any date in the format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: You are returning a `string` from the method where the method signature is `DateTime`. Either change the method signature to return a `string` or convert the string back to `DateTime`

Comment: I thought of this and tried to return DateTime.Parse(result) instead of result, but then I get XSLT error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

Comment: well, have you made sure your _input_ actually **is** a valid datetime in the format `yyyyMMdd`? because -spoiler - it isn't. maybe if you could show us a sample of the input breaking your code?

Comment: hmm.. its "20220630"

Comment: A value of type DateTime just contains a date. That date does *not* have any format - format applies *only* when you convert it to a string (or have the debugger convert it to a string so it can display it to you)

Comment: Keep the ParseExact with those parameters, just remove the ToString at the end (and fix the type of `result`, of course)

Comment: I tried to do this but I am getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'". What typo are you speaking of by the way? I do not see it

Comment: Remove the `ToString` and just return the result: `return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration, but I still got "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" :(

Comment: And what string are you passing in?

Comment: Just realized that I am passing yyyy-MM-dd. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am updating my question now

Comment: So I tried using your code with yyyy-MM-dd, but did not work yet.. hmm

Comment: You need to tell us what value you are passing in so we can help. Use ACTUAL values.

Comment: I am passing this: 2021-09-10

Comment: So, here is proof that it works https://dotnetfiddle.net/Twqz7W

Comment: Then the issue must be within the XSLT - since I still get the error message 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'. Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_datetime.htm for correct datetime . The format is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` . For xs:date the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Could you share the xslt-code?

Comment: Hi Siebe, I have now updated the question so it contains the xslt code. Thanks a lot for wanting to help me - the issue have not been solved yet :(

Comment: I would just do the conversion in pure XSLT without calling an extension function. What version of XSLT are you running? Is it XSLT 1.0 or is it XSLT 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: Hi Conal, I'm using xslt-1.0.

Comment: DavidG, your solution solved my issue. Thanks a lot. I cannot mark your comment as the answer, though

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `2021-09-10` would parse with `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

I guess you want e.g. `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am still getting the xslt error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' using this code.

Comment: @Zebraboard, one of the earlier commenters even set up a dotnetfiddle to show the C# code does work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Twqz7W.

Comment: yeah I see. The C# code definitely does work. Need to figure out what is wrong with the xslt

Answer (score 0):

You just want to remove the `-` characters from the date string?

That's simple to do in pure XSLT using the XPath [`translate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) function to convert the `-` characters to a zero-length string.

Sample input:

```xml
<Extraction>
  <Row>
    <AsOfDate>2021-09-10</AsOfDate>
  </Row>
</Extraction>
```

XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="ExtractDate" select="
        translate(
          /Extraction/Row[1]/AsOfDate[1], 
          '-', 
          ''
        )
      "/>
      <result><xsl:value-of select="$ExtractDate"/></result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<result>20210910</result>
```

Comment: Hmm, this might be able to do the trick, but the input 2021-09-10 can change from time to time - e.g. to 2021-10-10.

Comment: That XPath function simply removes the `-` characters from the text you pass it.